# hbase store multiple values for one key

Tags: database, hbase

how to store multiple email and phone number for one person in hbase?
or store multiple member and account ,  .... for a group?
in cassandra there is "set" data type that can do this but searching in that is problem. how to implement multiple value for a key in hbase?

for example we want to store personal information

- `person` | `email` | `phone number`
- `a` | `a@hotemail.com` , `a@gmail.com`| `323232`  , `42526672`
- `b`| `b@gmail.com` | `545465464`  ,   `46467464`

Comment: example data  with more details required.

Comment: person id -> could have multiple values for the same rowkey. which is natural in hbase. what exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: i want to store multiple email for one person and also multiple phone number for him  for example person1 has 2 email and 1 phone number and person 2 has 3 email and 2 phone number

Comment: yes this is possible in hbase, as shown in above format where you have a column email and your are storing multiple email ids which are comma seperated. what is problem here?

Comment: i think it doesn't have good performance in read or update or add an email i write this format to explain my problem

Comment: There are no data types in HBase like Cassandra, everything is serialized bytes. The way you store multiple values for a single column(qualifier) is by storing multiple versions. Have a look at https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#versions

Answer (score 0):

I can give a "not good enough " solution:

you can save the email,phone ... info as qualifier and "email", "user" string as value.

like this:

```
a@gamil.com email
b@gamil.com email
3242 phone
```

then add/delete is just a put/delete operation, and update can be done as a delete+add operation. Only get operation is a little troublesome, you need to get by rowkey and filter by value manually.

And another disadvantage is people can't have same string as both phone and email, but I think this doesn't affect much.

Comment: thank you for your answer so when i want  to use hive or phoenix for query and have to map column and know column's name what should i do?